# Convert an image from 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAx8AA...' to an image file

Tags: .net, image

I'm not sure of the name of the format that I'm receiving this data in, but it always begins with 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAx8AA...' and they tell me it's a png.

I need to save this to disk and view the png file.

When I save it as is, I get 'not a valid format' type of error, so I'm thinking I need to convert it somehow.

Can anyone offer any help? (I'm doing this in .NET)

Edit: After looking an the suggestion below, I found this piece of code that worked:

```
Function Base64ToImage(ByVal base64string As String) As System.Drawing.Image
    'Setup image and get data stream together
    Dim img As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim MS As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim b64 As String = base64string.Replace(" ", "+")
    Dim b() As Byte

    'Converts the base64 encoded msg to image data
    b = Convert.FromBase64String(b64)
    MS = New System.IO.MemoryStream(b)

    'creates image
    img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(MS)

    Return img
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is base64 string.. you need to convert base64 to image

Comment: Thank you for the response... but I'm still struggling. I've been at this all day.
If I have
Dim strImage as string = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAx8AA..."
How would I convert that?

Answer (score 0):

The PNG image is encoded as a [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) string.
All you need to do is convert the string into a byte array, and write it to disk.

```cs
string pngImage = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAx8AA..."; // base64 string
byte[] pngByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(pngImage);
string path = "C:\\Users\\etc\\etc\\image.png";
File.WriteAllBytes(path, pngByteArray); // Saves the image to disk
```